# Are units in rigid (autonomous) categories some sort of natural transformation?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

In a [rigid category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rigid+monoidal+category) $\mathcal{C}$, let us choose left and right duals and left and right (co)units for every object. This gives us, for example, a dualisation functor $-^*:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$, mapping every object onto its right dual.

_What kind of gadget is the map that sends every object $X$ onto its right unit $h_X: I \to X \otimes X^*$?

It's clearly not a natural transformation $h: \mathrm{const}_I \to - \otimes -^*$, since it doesn't satisfy the naturality condition:
$$h_Y \circ 1_I \neq (f \otimes f^*) \circ h_X$$
But it satisfies something similar:
$$(1_Y \otimes f^*) \circ h_Y = (f \otimes 1_{X^*}) \circ h_X$$
This holds because it is the definition of $f^*$ (using the snake identities). What kind of condition is this for $h$? Is this some generalisation of naturality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of it as a [extranatural transformation](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extranatural+transformation) or a [dinatural transformation](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dinatural+transformation). In fact the equation you wrote out is precisely the dinaturality condition in question.